# setInterval functions not running when app in background

Tags: javascript, google-maps, timer, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm developing a simple app with phonegap which every 30 seconds send user current coordinates to my database via ajax call.It works very well

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
            SetLocationUpdates();
        }, 30000);
         });
```

If the app is in the foreground there is no problem and everything works fine, but if I open google maps app with this code

```
<div><a href="geo:41.897096,27.036545">Open maps app</div>
```

My app goes in the background(my app and google map app work separately.Two apps work at same time) and the interval function is not executed any more.

Is it possible to have the javascript code (a timer function) executing in the background with phonegap?

Edited:

I use cordova-plugin-background-mode(https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) but it still does not work.And alert give false.What is wrong with this?

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
    alert(cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isActive());
}, false);
```

Comment: Javascript timers are generally paused in modern browser when the context they are running in, i.e. the window, looses focus. Sounds like it works somewhat the same way in PhoneGap ?

Comment: what should I do?Should I use webworkers or are there any solution for this ?

Comment: Not sure, maybe someone else has a workaround for PhoneGap?

Comment: I try cordova-plugin-background-mode but it still does not work.I edited question and added this info to end of question

Comment: Hi, did you solve it? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes @Maddin ,I used background plugin

Comment: @user1688401 and it is working in the background? I made a setinterval and it is not working in the background. What was the trick?

Comment: don't use custom interval.Use any background geolocation plugin(that plugins has own interval)...If you use phonegap-javascript I cannot connect you and fix it if you have budget..If not use any background geolocation.I used different 3 background plugin for different apps all of works perfectly...Just use background geolocation

Comment: The problem is that I dont use it for geolocation, I want to use setinterval for a timer.

Comment: For mobile apps you must use background geolocation with setinterval

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem, and I think I just found one, though I haven't been able to fully try this out yet, I thought I'd post the answer here anyways, so you can try it out too.

One solution would be to set the timer in native code, instead of JavaScript, and there seems to be a Cordova plugin for just such a purpose:

https://github.com/dukhanov/cordova-background-timer

After installing the Cordova plugin, you can use it like this (pasted from the documentation):

```
var eventCallback = function() {
    // timer event fired
}

var successCallback = function() {
    // timer plugin configured successfully
}

var errorCallback = function(e) {
    // an error occurred
}

var settings = {
    timerInterval: 60000, // interval between ticks of the timer in milliseconds (Default: 60000)
    startOnBoot: true, // enable this to start timer after the device was restarted (Default: false)
    stopOnTerminate: true, // set to true to force stop timer in case the app is terminated (User closed the app and etc.) (Default: true)

    hours: 12, // delay timer to start at certain time (Default: -1)
    minutes: 0, // delay timer to start at certain time (Default: -1)
}

window.BackgroundTimer.onTimerEvent(eventCallback); // subscribe on timer event
// timer will start at 12:00
window.BackgroundTimer.start(successCallback, errorCallback, settings);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this plugin is only working for Android, right?

Comment: Yes, currently only for Android, though it probably wouldn't be too hard to add iOS to the plugin. If the project I'm looking into gets the green light, there is a chance I might do it my self.

Comment: how can I reach you?

Comment: I'll make a post here if I end up adding iOS platform to the plugin, or if I get it working in some other way.

Comment: okay thanks. I have noticed that the issue has to do with an other plugin: cordova-plugin-tts. I opened a case: https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts/issues/59 I got setinterval running in the bg-mode without the plugin, if I enable background mode within the timer-function. but if TTS is running before, it breaks the background mode.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still looking for an answer for this issue , or it can help someone else:
im sure that you are facing this problem in android so to resolve this you should add this piece of code after you add background-mode cordova plugin to your project :

```
this.backgroundMode.enable();
   this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(()=>{
       this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem the background plugin does not work, because it only activated when you switch / pause the app.

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
alert(cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isActive());
```

Your code above cannot return `isActive()` because the app does not pause / go to background at the time called.